# jQuery animation issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is kind of difficult to explain, so I'll paste the function, and explain what it does

```
function close(r){
    if(r !== undefined){
        $('#close').attr('name','1');
        $('#close').css({
            top: 30,
            left: 30
        });
        $('#close').html('First click here');
    }else{
        switch($('#close').attr('name')){
            case '1':
                $('#close').attr('name','2');
                $('#close').animate({
                    bottom: 30,
                    right: 30
                },1000);
                $('#close').html('Now click here');
            break;
            case '2':
                $('#close').attr('name','3');
                $('#close').animate({
                    bottom: 30,
                    left: 30
                },1000);
                $('#close').html('A now click here');
            break;
            case '3':
                $('#close').attr('name','4');
                $('#close').animate({
                    top: 30,
                    right: 30
                },1000);
                $('#close').html('And finally click here');
            break;
            case '4':
                $('#close').remove();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If you require explanation, here it goes

1. The close function is first called as `close(1)`. This sets the position to top: 30 and left: 30. Note that its position is already set to absolute in the stylesheet. This first part works, and wherever I choose to place it is obeyed.
2. The #close element has an oclick assigned to `close()`. Each time it is clicked, as you can see, a different action occurs. Everything works fine (i.e. the html and name attribute changes), except for the animation. The #close element remains stationary.
3. On the last click, the element successfully disappears.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Cheers

Gausie

Comment: that is horrible, horrible code. I may get flagged as offensive, but it may be worth refactoring that.

Comment: Not offensive - constructive! How would you do it?

Comment: At the very least, make the case statements call a function passing in the number and the string to display. That would be a good start, and you may find better things to do from there.

Comment: for starters, it looks like you could replace the switch entirely, with `$('#close').attr('name', (parseInt($('#close').attr('name'))+1).toString());`

Comment: (well not entirely, but hey....)

Comment: And then follow that with an if statement to perform each action? What's the benefit of that over my current method?

Comment: the benefit is if you change the id of '#close' you only have to do it once ;)

Comment: Jimmeh - that sounds sensible, and it did occur to me during coding. I'll see if it does anything..

Comment: cache $('#close') in an object rather than creating hundreds of separate jq objects var $el = $('#close'); then use $el....

Comment: All implemented, however none of these suggestions have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time round you set `left: 30px`. Second time round you set `right: 30px`. But `left: 30px` is still set. They are not exclusive properties; setting both is supposed to make the element expand to fit the amount of space between a 30px-left-edge and a 30px-right-edge.

However I'm guessing you have a fixed width on the `close` element. This leaves `left: 30px; right: 30px; width: 100px` which is [over-constrained](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width), causing the `right` property to be ignored, producing no movement. The same goes for `top`​/​`bottom`​/​`height`.

To animate between a left-aligned and right-aligned position you will need to script only one of `left` or `right`. To find out what the pixel position of `left` for a right-aligned position would be you will have to look at the size of the element's containing block. Assuming the containing block is the whole document:

```
<div id="close" style="background: red; position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 50px;">foo</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var close_step= 0;
    $('#close').click(function() {
        if (close_step>=4) {
            $(this).remove();
            return;
        }
        var w= $(window).width()-$(this).width()-30*2;
        var h= $(window).height()-$(this).height()-30*2;
        var x= [0, 1, 0, 1][close_step]*w+30;
        var y= [0, 1, 1, 0][close_step]*h+30;
        var pos= {left: x+'px', top: y+'px'};
        if (close_step===0)
            $(this).css(pos);
        else
            $(this).animate(pos);
        $(this).text([
            'First click here', 'Now click here', 'And now click here', 'And finally click here'
        ][close_step]);
        close_step++;
    }).click();
</script>
```

If `#close` were nested in a block with a `position`, you'd need to look at the width/height of that block instead of `window`.

Comment: What an awesome answer - thanks!
I had just worked out the overconstraining problem by inspecting them DOM. But thankyou so much!

Comment: How would one refer to the tactic of following an array with the key you wish to retrieve (`        $(this).text([
            'First click here', 'Now click here', 'And now click here', 'And finally click here'
        ][close_step]);`)?

Comment: hmmm... I don't know that there's a proper name for it as it's a fairly normal consequence of any language with array literals. I'll make up the name Inline Array Literal Dereferencing to make it sound posh.